# Stop bars from centering in chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am creating a bar chart using d3. To do so I looked at [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) code and changed it a little bit.

However what it does is centering the bars, and I would like the bars to start immediate at the bar y axis.

It looks like the issue comes from these 2 pieces of code:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .0);
```

and the last line of this one:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(graphObj)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.step); })
```

where the x(d.step) is responsible for the distance, the x is set at the var x = ...

Somehow I need to change this, but cant figure it out.
The distance is a bit different since I changed this:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
```

to this:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .0);
```

but it doesn't help much.

Can you help out here?

This is my code:

```
        $('#chartDiv').html('');

        var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 35, left: 50},
            width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .0);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");


        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(10, "");

        var svg = d3.select("#chartDiv").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


        graphObj.forEach(function(d) {
            d.step = +d.step;
            d.temp = +d.temp;
        });

        x.domain(graphObj.map(function(d) { return d.step; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(graphObj, function(d) { return d.temp; })]);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", "-40px")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Temperature");

        svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(graphObj)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function(d) { console.log(d.step, x.rangeBand(), x(d.step)); return x(d.step); })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.temp); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.temp); });

        if ($('#chartDiv').css('left').replace('px','') < 0) {
            $('#chartDiv').animate({
                left: 10
            }, 1000);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the `i` variable to the `.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.step); })`, like so: `.attr("x", function(d, i) { return x.rangeRoundBands() * i; })`, so it will go through the bars and place them one after the other (this might need some tweaking, can't do it properly without a jsfiddle) but should at least get you on the path of fixing it without issues

Comment: Great fixed it with this .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x.rangeBand() * i; }) so if you only change the x.rangeRoundBands() to x.rangeBand() it works

Comment: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangeRoundBands rangeRoundBands should work as well, it's just that it rounds up the width of the elements so they don't end up having a width with a decimal number ;)

Comment: weird, using that I got errors... I will test it some more. 
Another point now is that the ticks of the xaxis are not in line with the bars now. Any insight of how to do this?

Comment: if you could set up a jsfiddle or codepen or whatever it would surely help track down that issue

Comment: I will try to create something. though I am using backbone as well so my data is a bit all around ;-)

Comment: never mind I will leave the xaxis values out, since I can go up to a 1000 anyway ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aups693a/2/ I changed the xaxis from ordinal to linear and reduced the width of the bars a little bit, but you can tweak those values easily